# bluetooth in libgdx project on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, libgdx

Can anyone give me a piece of advice about using bluetooth in `libgdx` games on Android?
My problem is that the whole code is in MyGame project and in `MyGame-Android` there is only `MainActivity` class that starts the game on Android.

I can get bluetooth to work in normal Android application but `MyGame libgdx` project can't see classes that are in `MyGame-Android project`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use non-multiplatform code in libgdx, you should create an interface on the agnostic project (MyGame), and implement it on the native project (MyGame-Android). Then, on the native project create the implementor object and pass it to the MyGame instance. The interface will hold all the methods that you said are not accessible (a tip: try to can encapsulate the most you can regarding the bluetooth management and expose only methods relevant to your game, so you don't have to create a huge interface).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else finds there way here on their journey to create Bluetooth-able apps.
I think the best starting place is the Android Developer guide to get a firm grasp and understanding of Bluetooth on its own - Create a working application with what they have there  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

After that, using the method above, you can implement the code. A working example is http://algorhymes.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/java-bluetooth-on-android-with-and-wo-libgdx/ but I recommend understanding the Bluetooth first, it makes debugging much much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, but I needed kind of the same, so I'm sharing.

I create and app on libgdx and add an implementation to manage bluetooth low energy connections in android and ios. (both are working with a cadence sensor)

All the code is on github if you want

https://github.com/carlgira/ble-cadence-app

I was not sure how the IOS part would work, but basically I translated a Swift bluetooth APP to the robovm java api. There are some differences in names and stuff, but is was almost the same.