# Robovm - SQLite and Bluetooth 4 (BLE)

Tags: java, ios, robovm, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible with RovoVM to use native iOS SQLite and Bluetooth 4 (BLE) functionality writing Javacode only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer from the [same question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robovm/BMxd9VVfQmw/jr-GHPeL8lwJ) in the [roboVM Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/robovm):

> SQLite can definitely be used. Either through JDBC or directly using the classes in the SQLite.* package. Check out the ContractR sample for an example of how to use SQLite over JDBC: https://github.com/robovm/robovm-samples/tree/master/ContractR. The relevant code is in the `core/` and `ios/` folders.
>
> And we have bindings for the CoreBluetooth iOS framework so that should be doable as well. I don't know if anyone tested the CoreBluetooth bindings yet but if you do please let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but just sharing.

It's totally possible, I created and app in libgdx (game engine) that uses robovm. To not repeat myself more, just see the reference to other stackoverflow question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69119416/6484989